# Stage.setIconified() and Stage.isIconified() not acting properly

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to write a simple method to toggle whether my window is minimized (i.e. iconified). I am getting strange behavior. Below is runnable code that illustrates the problem.

I am getting the same results on Gnome 3.20.4 and XFCE 4.12. I haven't tested this in any other environment yet.

---

1. If the window is not maximized, the code works as expected, but the reported state is incorrect at times. Here is the output from the code below. I have put notes (`<--`) next to lines where the textual output doesn't match the visual output.

---

**Windows Not Maximized Behavior**

```
Before call  (Note: Window appears iconified)
    isIconified(): true
    isMaximized(): true

Setting iconified to false

After call (Note: Window now appears restored, not maximized) 
    isIconified(): true   <-- The window is visually not iconified 
    isMaximized(): true   <-- The window is visually not maximized


Before call (Note: Window still appears restored, not maximized) 
    isIconified(): false  <-- One second later, the report is accurate
    isMaximized(): false

Setting iconified to true

After call  (Note: Window now appears iconified) 
    isIconified(): true
    isMaximized(): true
```

---

2. If the window is maximized, the code does not work as expected. Instead, it is a three-step process. The first call iconifies, the second call restores, and the third call doesn't make any visual changes.

---

**Windows Maximized Behavior**

```
Before call (Note: Window appears iconified)
    isIconified(): true
    isMaximized(): true

Setting iconified to false

After call (Note: Window appears maximized)
    isIconified(): true <-- Does not match visual
    isMaximized(): true


Before call (Note: Window appears maximized)
    isIconified(): true <-- Does not match visual
    isMaximized(): true

Setting iconified to false

After call (Note: Window appears maximized)
    isIconified(): false
    isMaximized(): false  <-- Does not match visual


Before call (Note: Window appears maximized)
    isIconified(): false
    isMaximized(): false  <-- Does not match visual

Setting iconified to true

After call (Note: Window appears iconified)
    isIconified(): true
    isMaximized(): true

<Now it loops>

Before call (Note: Window appears iconified)
    isIconified(): true
    isMaximized(): true

Setting iconified to false

After call (Note: Window appears maximized)
    isIconified(): true  <-- Does not match visual
    isMaximized(): true

...
```

Here is the runnable code:

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageTest extends Application {

    Stage stage;

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        launch ( args );
    }

    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setResizable( true );
        stage.show( );

        Thread thread = new Thread ( () -> {
            while ( true ) {
                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    toggleMinimized();
                } );
                try {
                    Thread.sleep ( 1000 );
                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.setDaemon( true );
        thread.start();

    }

    public void toggleMinimized() {

        System.out.println ( "Before call" );
        System.out.println ( "\tisIconified(): " + stage.isIconified() );
        System.out.println ( "\tisMaximized(): " + stage.isIconified() );
        System.out.println ();

        if ( stage.isIconified() ) {
            System.out.println ( "Setting iconified to false" );
            System.out.println ();
            stage.setIconified( false );
        } else {
            System.out.println ( "Setting iconified to true" );
            System.out.println ();
            stage.setIconified( true );
        }


        System.out.println ( "After call" );
        System.out.println ( "\tisIconified(): " + stage.isIconified() );
        System.out.println ( "\tisMaximized(): " + stage.isMaximized() );
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a typo in your program you have 2 stage.isIconified()'s when you should have one

```
public void toggleMinimized() {
    System.out.println ( "Before call" );
    System.out.println ( "\tisIconified(): " + stage.isIconified() );
    System.out.println ( "\tisMaximized(): " + stage.isIconified() );
```

It should be

```
public void toggleMinimized() {
    System.out.println ( "Before call" );
    System.out.println ( "\tisIconified(): " + stage.isIconified() );
    System.out.println ( "\tisMaximized(): " + stage.isMaximized() );
```